# Freetype invalid preprocessor directive Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, freetype2

I've downloaded the latest version of FreeType and want to get the source code running in my program. I'm programming in Eclipse and I've copied all the Freetype files into my project. I've listed them under ProjectName/Source/FreeType2/..

I've added compiler include directories for the new folders, so my GCC C++ compiler knows where to look for them. However, if I build my project, an error occurs on the last line of the following code:

```
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_WINFONTS_H
#include FT_INTERNAL_DEBUG_H
```

I did some research and the macro file `FT_INTERNAL_DEBUG_H` is defined as `<internal/ftdebug.h>`. The file is present in my system and the macro file `FT_WINFONTS_H` compiles like a charm! I think it's got something to do with my directory stucture somehow. How should I change my directory structure in order to get things compiled succesfully? My current structure is like this:

```
ProjectName
    Source
        FreeType2
            devel
            docs
            include
                config
                internal
            objs
            src
```

I know I used two "source" folders, but this shouldn't be the problem, right?

The error message I get is `Invalid preprocessor directive: #include FT_INTERNAL_DEBUG_H`

Thank you for your time ;)

Comment: Please post the *exact* error message.

Comment: The first error I get is `function undeclared here` which made me look at the top of the source file and there I saw the `Invalid preprocessor directive: #include FT_INTERNAL_DEBUG_H` error. Which made me thinking the file is not present in the correct directory?